# Angular2 application with springboot using maven

Tags: spring, maven, angular, spring-boot

I am new to Springframework. I created a Springboot application and expose rest services. Now I want to consume my rest services in angular2. I am not sure how to create folder structure for my application. Should I create angular2 app in src/main/resources folder using angular cli? or as I am exposing rest services so should I create a separate angular project and consume the services? But if user this approach it will run on two different ports on localhost and I get CrosOrigin error.
In production I will deploy the application on same server. It will be a one website.
One more point I am using Maven and STS tool suit to create springboot application.

Comment: You just need to set the respective header on your server to be CORS-compliant. So no big deal if you've got two separate applications. Regarding your structure, you are free to do whatever you want. There are good reasons for both approaches.

Comment: I got it. I deployed two different applications on localhost and enable CROS. what about deploying in production system?

Comment: If you go for 2 separate applications in your local development, you should go for the same set up in all other environments, too. Imo, the more equal your environments are, the easier it is to maintain and debug them.

Comment: you are correct. But then what will be the solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Solution for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find some sample code but even in Springboot application you have to run spring and angular application on two different ports on local host. So the best way to solve the problem is to create two application expose services in spring boot and use in angular client side. While running on local use enable CORS.
Another way is to use JHipster. They recently release JHipster 4 which support angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring-Boot novice using AngularJS you might be checking out [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io) (which actually is a combination of these two projects), which might serve you with some best practices.

Currently based on AngularJS 1 - it's not Angular2 yet - however they're busy porting it to version 2 (see [progress](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4549), see [this](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/ng2-ui-router) branch).

Alternatively there's also a guide [on how to create a standalone Spring-Boot application with AngularJS](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application) (1).

Comment: I looked into JHipster, but I am not using Angular-1. I am using angular-2.  And still JHipster as you also mentioned not based on Angular-2

Comment: Did you also check out their Angular2 branch:https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/ng2-ui-router? Just curious how far they are already... I'm also waiting for their version 2 support.

Comment: I am using JHipster 4.3.0. And they are using Angular 4 now. Its great product.